# How can The Model class be a subclass of the Document class?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-models

[image: Mongoose docs]

The underline statement does not make any sense to me. I believe mongoose devs didn't publish their docs wrong and I'm missing a point.

`console.log(mongoose.Model instanceof mongoose.Document)`

Also when I run the code above, it outputs false.

Can someone explain what docs really want to imply?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. It is not so satisfying but for those of people who are also curios about the question can check [this link](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9533).

Briefly, even if we cannot see the behavior explicitly, it is in the [source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/fcc13413acc7bf1454ffa7270587a898aec8b7d0/lib/model.js#L106-L116).